# What is the difference between print(np.median(aqi_array)) and print(aqi_array.median)

Tags: python, median

I wonder what is the difference  between

```
print(np.median(aqi_array))
```

and

```
print(aqi_array.median())
```

I can use

```
print(aqi_array.std())
```

or

```
print(aqi_array.max())
```

but not

```
print(aqi_array.median())
```

Can you please explain why?

Comment: I think it depends on the object type of aqi_array, if the object implete the median function, then you can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.median(aqi_array)` uses the NumPy library to calculate the median of the array `aqi_array`, `aqi_array.median()` is used with Pandas DataFrame or Series objects to calculate the median, but it seems `aqi_array` is not a Pandas object.

You can still use `std()` and max()`on`aqi_array` because those methods are available for NumPy arrays and other data structures in Python.